# Angular 2. Passing data on event from child component to all other

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

This concept looking ugly as for me, compare to Angular 1. I still can't get how should I inform about changes all other components. Let's say I have HeaderComponent where I have button changing language property from 'en' to 'de' for example. I bind event in EventEmitter, but how I can get new property in the other components?

```
    import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input }          from '@angular/core'
    import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router }  from '@angular/router';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Component({
        selector: 'bp-header',
        templateUrl: 'app/header.component.html',
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    export class HeaderComponent {
        isActive: number;
    language: string = "en";
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.isActive = 1;
    }
    public setLanguage = (language: string) => {
        if (this.language === language) { return }
        else { this.language = language };
        this.dataService.changeLanguage(language);
    }
    private setActive(active: number) {
        if (this.isActive === active) return;
        this.isActive = active;
    }
    }
```

This is another child component. Am I right that Input should listen for changes?

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './data.person';
import { Article } from './data.article';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router }  from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'bp-home',
    templateUrl: "app/home.component.html",
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HomeComponent {
        language: string;
article: Article;
persons: Person[];
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.subscription = dataService.languageChanged$.subscribe(
        language => {
            this.language = language;
        });
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.article = this.language == "ru" ? this.articleRu : this.articleEn;
    this.persons = this.language == "ru" ? this.personsRu : this.personsEn;
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
ngOnChanges() {
    this.article = this.language == "ru" ? this.articleRu : this.articleEn;
    this.persons = this.language == "ru" ? this.personsRu : this.personsEn;
}
```

Here is data service:

```
import { Component, Injectable}          from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private language = new Subject<string>();
  languageChanged$ = this.language.asObservable();
  changeLanguage(language: string) {
    this.language.next(language);
  }
}
```

Comment: you should not use `EventEmitter` rather you should use `shared service` having single instance.

Comment: @micronyks, ok, but how component will know about changes?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html check this tutorial and look for `Parent and children communicate via a service`. You can use that approach anywhere when routing is used. If header make any changes, changes are done in service and that changes will be sent to any component using `Rxjs- subject`. You have to first understand this example.

Comment: It look like this service able to communicate only between parent - child, but what if I want to commucate between child - child?

Comment: Nope. Using `subject` you can subscribe to that changes anywhere you want. This is just any example. come up with plunker I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: @micronyks, yes, please, I still can't get this idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118075/discussion-between-micronyks-and-andrey-shedko).

Comment: @micronyks, please add comment as answer.

Comment: have you figured it out?

Comment: @micronyks, well, not really. Now needed value passed successfully, but this not makes another component changes. Please see updates.

Comment: Look like in HomeComponent events ngOnChanges just not firing.

Comment: Can you please post the code of `class DataService`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I did add DataService class. Actually I solve the problem of using DataService in ChildComponent already.